# Firebase cloud messaging service alternatives

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm wondering, are there any great alternatives to Firebase Cloud Messaging Service?

Please tell me if you have great Cloud Messaging Services in mind, which can be used for Android and iOS platforms.

And please also give the pros and cons and explain them in details.

Thank you.
I appreciate any help :)

Comment: I use Parse-Server.

Answer (score 3):

Best alternative is [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_IN&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=cloud_computing_b&sc_content=aws_spell_e&sc_detail=amazonweb%20services&sc_category=cloud_computing&sc_segment=109576384021&sc_matchtype=e&sc_country=IN&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!109576384021!e!!g!!amazonweb%20services&ef_id=V8uK3gAABLSBOFot:20161221040735:s). If you are veryfamiliar with firebase you can understand this quickly. All these are automated. You dont need to design database schema from the basics. And you can use node js but this one you have to implement all the functionalities you needed for your application.

Comment: AWS' SNS uses  GCM for android anyway